# retrieve the symbolic and target link of `ls -la`

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, symlink

I have the following code:

```
  #bin/sh
  symbolic=''
  target=''
  ls -la | grep "\->" | while read line
  do
      target=${line##* }
  done
```

which will print out all targets files (where symbolic links point to).

Now, I would like to add the following constraints:

1. parse the symbolic link file name (the word before ->) into the var "symbolic". (I would like to treat it as the 3rd last word of the string)
2. only parse the symbolic link which points to a valid/existing place.

If I don't want to use "echo | awk", are there any other ways to achieve this?

Thanks!

**Update & Final Solutions**

```
  #bin/sh
  find . -maxdepth 1 -type l -xtype d | while read line
  do
      symlink=$line
      target=$(readlink line)
  done
```

Comment: See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Apart from the usual problems with parsing the output of `ls`, the code above will fail on directories that contain files with names like `X->Y`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` to list the valid symlinks in the current directory:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type l -xtype f
```

Note the value of the `-xtype` argument, which indicates what type of file the link links to. In this example, I've used `f` for regular file. If needed, you can replace this with another of the find types like `d` for directory.

Answer (score 0):

This Bash code will list all symlinks in the current directory that reference existing targets:

```
shopt -s nullglob   # Handle empty directories
shopt -s dotglob    # Handle files whose names start with '.'

for file in * ; do
    if [[ -L $file && -e $file ]] ; then
        printf '"%s" is a symlink to an existing target\n' "$file"
    fi
done
```

If you need to get the target of a symlink, the `readlink` command does it on
many systems:

```
target=$(readlink -- "$file")
```